# Vanilla Javascript how to check if clicked element is last item

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to do a check on if the current clicked element is the last element. Here is what I got so far:

```
<div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 1 </div>
<div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 2 </div>
<div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 3 </div>
<div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 4 </div>
```

then my javascript:

```
onClick(e){
    let clicked = e.target;
 
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
    let lastchild = items[items.length - 1];

    if(clicked === lastchild) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

but for some reason this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are there other `.item` elements on the page that are found in other elements? That is because `document.querySelectorAll('.item')` returns _all_ the elements that matches the class in the entire document, not just in the parent node that contains the 5 items.

Comment: @Terry no there no other `.item` elements

Comment: Your code should work. However, if you want to be sure, change `items` to be `clicked.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.item')`

Comment: @TusharShahi Why? `===` should work when comparing if a node is identical to another.

Comment: Compare the target with the parent's `lastElementChild`?

Comment: This isn't vanilla JS, though? [it does work using vanilla](https://jsbin.com/wujagivexu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: @VLAZ Based on the shorthand syntax used, I think OP is using VueJS.

Comment: @Terry That is indeed a valid assumption. But the title says otherwise. There is also no [mcve], so I can't even begin guessing what's wrong. I've not used Vue enough to know at a glance if this is completely correct. *Assuming* it's Vue and not some other framework.

Comment: @ST80 Are you using VueJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only works if there are no other `.item` elements on the page, since `document.querySelectorAll('.item')` returns *all* elements from the document that matches the selector.

If you change the scope of the selector so that it only queries the immediate parent node of the element, then it will work: see example below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onClick(e) {
      console.log('Item clicked');
      let clicked = e.target;

      let items = clicked.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.item');
      let lastchild = items[items.length - 1];

      if (clicked === lastchild) {
        console.log('Last child clicked');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 1 </div>
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 2 </div>
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 3 </div>
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 4 </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 1 </div>
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 2 </div>
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 3 </div>
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 4 </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 1 </div>
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 2 </div>
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 3 </div>
    <div class="item" @click="onClick"> Item 4 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if `e.target.nextElementSibling === null` which ensures that no other sibling element present

Comment: What about `<div class="container"><div class="item"> only item</div><p>I am not an item</p></div>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the array length method and can iterate over the array and can use the index to find the last element by simply adding 1 into the iteration counter.

```
var itemLength = items.length;

for(var i = 0;i < itemLength;i++){
var item = items[i];

// Do something if is the last iteration of the array
if((i + 1) == (itemLength)){
    console.log("Last iteration with item : " + item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why use a loop? You can immediately know which the last item is because it's at the last index. And since you know the length, you know the last index: `items[items.length - 1]`  is the last item.